# Cannot delete breakpoints in C# Express (2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I've been working on something for quite a while, and during this time I've had to move my project between computers and I think this has somehow caused my breakpoints to become corrupt.

I can't seem to delete breakpoints. If I right-click the breakpoint and click delete, it disappears on the screen, but comes back the next time I debug.

Where does VC# store breakpoints? It doesn't seem to be in my project folder as far as I can see...

I've tried deleting the PDB files too but that has no effect.

Comment: Have you also tried deleting the whole content of the bin\debug folder?

Comment: Try deleting (or renaming just to be safe) your `<SolutionName>.suo` file.

Comment: try deleting the breakpoints from the breakpoints window instead of the editor

Comment: I'd just delete the `{PROJECT}.suo` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. You have to enable hidden files/folders in Windows Explorer and delete the .suo file in VS Projects Folder\Your Project.

@Rob Delete All Breakpoints is not available in the Express versions.

Comment: oh thought that would be a common feature

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints are stored in the .suo file, so to reset everything to default try deleting yoursolutionname.suo file contained in the solution root folder ...

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+f9 or Debug >> Delete All Breakpoints